# Animated GIF in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder

I am trying to add a GIF image in my flex application. However it is not showing animations. Anyone have idea how to make a GIF image work in flex

```
import mx.managers.PopUpManager;
            
            private function onCreationCompleted():void
            {
                mx.managers.PopUpManager.centerPopUp(this);
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Image x="127" y="137" source="@Embed('assets/loading.gif')" width="87" height="85"/> 
    <s:Label x="88" y="73" text="Loading... Please wait" width="164" height="56" verticalAlign="middle" textAlign="center"/>
```

Comment: Can you show us HOW you have added the gif in the flex application? Did you embed the gif image?

Comment: actually i am creating a popup of component mxml. This mxml has embeded s type image.

Comment: Please add the code that you have used :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the looks of it Flex does not provide support for animated gifs. It would be much easier to use a swf.

There are some very nice [loading animations provided in this link](http://www.designswan.com/archives/18-flash-loading-animations.html). Use a `SWFLoader`.

However if you do want to use animated gifs in Flex read this blogpost.

http://iamjosh.wordpress.com/2009/02/03/animated-gifs-in-flex/

You have to create the class shown in that blog post and add as3gif as a package.

you can [download as3gif from here](http://code.google.com/p/as3gif/)

Answer (score -1):

I convert gif to swf and it animated.